# pip install failed with errors "Command errored with exit status 1:"

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio, librosa

I've been trying to install `librosa` packages via `pip`. It keeps failing with these errors.
Other packages such as `pyaudio`, `PyQt5` give a similar error. Why are these packages giving errors? Any ideas?

```
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-record-1mj1e170/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/include/python3.8/llvmlite
         cwd: /private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/
    Complete output (14 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.38.0', 'full': 'f0365b91ce1e1f74c68785c6d0067f32f89857d9'}
    running build_ext
    /Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/bin/python3.8 /private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    LLVM version... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 220, in <module>
        main()
      File "/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 214, in main
        main_posix('osx', '.dylib')
      File "/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 134, in main_posix
        raise RuntimeError(msg) from None
    RuntimeError: Could not find a `llvm-config` binary. There are a number of reasons this could occur, please see: https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#using-pip for help.
    error: command '/Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/bin/python3.8' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-install-bpcub3_y/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/1g/8vqsn9yd48xf1y82n0g3fmdw0000gn/T/pip-record-1mj1e170/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/choijaeik/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/include/python3.8/llvmlite Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you follow the suggestions in the error message to `please see: https://llvmlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-guide/install.html#using-pip for help`

Comment: Did you add python to the path while installing? if not I recommend you reinstall and make sure to check the "add python to path" checkbox while installing. This worked for me in the past.

Comment: what do I have to reinstall? Sorry i'm new to python so I need some more details.